# Split one object into List of objects - JAVA8 Solution required

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I have the following code where i have a single employee object with multiple roles. i want to split this single employee object into multiple employee objects with each object have just ONE role.

```
public class Employee {
   private String empId;
   private String empName;
   private List<String> empRoles;
 }
```

Now i have a method with return type List

```
public List<Employee> splitEmployeObj(Employee emp) {
   // code logic goes here 
 }
   // sample input : { empId:'123',empName:'john',empRoles:['Developer','Tester'] }
   // sample output : [ { empId:'123', empName:'john',empRoles : ['Developer'] },
                        { empId:'123', empName:'john',empRoles : ['Tester']]
```

can someone help with an efficient java8 solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I suggest you remove the prefix `emp` from the fields, as the class is already named `Employee`. Just `id`, `name` and `roles` are sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Stream over the roles and map to a new Employee:

```
public List<Employee> splitEmployeObj(Employee emp) {
    return emp.getEmpRoles()
            .stream()
            .map(role -> new Employee(emp.getEmpId(), emp.getEmpName(), Collections.singletonList(role)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help but it's basically a heavy object in the real application and i cannot manually set each field to a new object. That's the problem i have.

Comment: So if you can't create a new object what exactly are you looking for?  Your requirement and caveat to meeting that seem to be at odds.  You might also want to update your question explaining this and any other limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Lombok framework and then use @Eritrean's solution:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true) // here is the magic
public class Employee {
  private String empId;
  private String empName;
  private List<String> empRoles;

  public List<Employee> explode() {
    return emp.getEmpRoles().stream()
        .map(role -> this.toBuilder()
                       .empRoles(singletonList(role))
                       .build()
        )
        .collect(toList());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a few public things in your `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee {
   private String empId;
   private String empName;
   private List<String> empRoles = new ArrayList<>();

   public Employee(String empId, String empName, String... empRoles) {
       this.empId = empId;
       this.empName = empName;
       for (String role: empRoles) {
           this.empRoles.add(role);
       }
   }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public List<String> getEmpRoles() {
        return empRoles;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public List<Employee> splitEmployeObj(Employee emp) {
    return emp.getEmpRoles().stream()
            .map(role -> new Employee(emp.getEmpId(), emp.getEmpName(), role))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```